# What is the minimal version of kernel on which ARM Slackware 14.0 will run?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, slackware

I'm running Debian Lenny on a ARM NAS with 2.6.24 kernel. Debian in this version is missing many important security fixes and software patches, but when I've tried to run Debian Squeeze on the same box I've received "kernel too old" error message and the system did not boot. I cannot upgrade the kernel so I'm wondering if ARM version of Slackware 14.0 would run on this kernel. Can you confirm that? Of course I'm aware of security bugs in this version of kernel, but am not able to do anything with it.